# React Native - tabBarOnPress can only access state in the initialRouteName tab - createMaterialBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, state, react-navigation, tabnavigator

**Given:**

App.js

```
// import...
    export default class App extends Component<Props> {

      render() {
        return (
          <Root>
            <MenuProvider>
              <AppStackNavigator />    
            </MenuProvider>
          </Root>
        );
      }
    }

    const AppStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
      Main : {
        screen: MainScreen
      },
      Detail : {
        screen: DetailScreen
      }
    })
```

MainScreen.js

```
// import...
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  // ...
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
        <AppTabNavigator screenProps={{ rootNavigation: this.props.navigation}}/>
    )
  }
}

const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeTab: {
        screen: HomeTab
    },
    ExerciseTab: {
        screen: ExerciseTab
    },
    LovedTab: {
        screen: LovedTab
    },
    FilterTab: {
        screen: FilterTab
    },
    SettingTab: {
        screen: SettingTab
    }
}, {
    labeled: true,
    shifting: true,
    initialRouteName: 'HomeTab', 
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
    backBehavior: 'none'
});
```

HomeTab.js - tabBarOnPress could access state via params

```
//import...
export default class HomeTab extends Component {
//...
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name="md-home" style={{color: tintColor}} />
    ),
    title: 'Home',
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation}) => {
      navigation.state.params.setCurrentScreen(navigation.state);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      ...this.props.navigation.state.params,
      setCurrentScreen: (state) => {
        this._getFontSize();       
        this.props.navigation.navigate(state.key);
      }
    });
  }
```

LovedTab.js - the same code as Hometab does not work :(

```
// import..
export default class LovedTab extends Component {
//...
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name="md-heart" style={{color: tintColor}} />
    ),
    title: 'Loved',
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation}) => {
      navigation.state.params.setCurrentScreen(navigation.state);
      // params is undefined - setting the same as HomeTab.js
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:**
How can I catch the press event on the LovedTab in order to update the state (reload the current tab). It seems that setParams only works on the first tab (initialRouteName).

My main goal is re-load the LovedTab whenever the tab is focused. Do you have any other idea?